# Added webpart to subsite but users cant see it

Tags: web-part

Ive created a clickable web part within the sub site main page. Users have access to the site but they cant see the web part I added. If I click on site settings and there is no web parts "section" to check if they have rights, any ideas what Im doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are few things you should check:

1. Make sure your page is 'Published'
2. Make sure your web part is not closed on the page
3. Go to the web parts maintenance gallery and check if the web part is available( Short cut - append the url with "?contents=1"
4. Also make sure that users do have access to the list/library you are using as a web part on the page

Comment: Another thing to check, though unlikely, is if Audience Targeting has been set within the web part properties. If you want everyone to see the web part, make sure you're not targeting a specific audience. Details: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33D84CB6-14ED-4E53-A426-74C38EA32293 (the section near the bottom called 'target a web part to an audience')